# How can you connect python to the Microsoft store and download an app?

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if there are modules, or code snippets to create a program that connects to the Microsoft store, in the background, and download an app(without pyAutoGUI). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Official API's for accessing Microsoft store, A Possible solution is to use `requests` library or other equivalent to create a bot that can access various fields available on the website and navigate through, if you always want a certain(Same) application to be downloaded may be you can go directly to that links page and use get request for the download button as submit, this should work in theory, but again this will also keep breaking in short durations as Microsoft keeps making changes to it's website.

P.S. You might want to fool the website by adding headers to your request.